# How to determine if a line from a input file is the last line? c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, if-statement, input, eof

I have written a program to check for balanced curly brackets in a .cpp file. The program works fine and finds the syntax error, displays the number of the line with the problem and then exits.

But I have to display a different error message if the error is at the last line of the input cpp file.

I have tried to implement it like following way but I think it is wrong. It doesn't work anyway :)

```
else
                {
                    if(current == inputFile.eof()) //THIS IS WHAT I TRIED
                    {
                        cout << "Syntax error at the end of the program.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Syntax error in line: " << current << "\n";
                        errorFound == true;
                    }
                }
```

I did not give the complete code because I think a simple if condition with the correct variable will solve this. If you need it, I can post the code later.

EDIT: Larger piece of the code is given as requested. counter is an int variable that is updated every line by counter++.

```
for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++)
        {
            if (line[i] == '{')
            {
                stack.push(current);
            }
            else if(line[i] == '}')
            {
                if (!stack.isEmpty())
                {
                    stack.pop(opening);
                    cout << "Code block: " << opening << " - " << current << "\n";
                }
                else
                {
                    if(current == inputFile.eof())
                    {
                        cout << "Syntax error at the end of the program.";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cout << "Syntax error in line: " << current << "\n";
                        errorFound == true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: It would be nice to know the complete code. That way, we can better find a solution to your code (of course, making a [mcve] would be even better!). Now, we can only guess how you read `current`, ... and thus not provide a good solution.

Comment: `eof` flag doesn't get set, unless you try to read **past** the end of file. This should be pointed out, in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/eof).

Comment: Maybe seeking to the end and reading backward till hitting `\n`, then an `ftell()` call give you the position. Whenever you pas this position then you are in the last line.

Comment: @Rakete1111 I edited the post.

Comment: @CinCout Yep, it was a poor attempt :)

Comment: @byetisener Maybe I'm missing something, but why not just `if (i == line.length() - 1);`?

Comment: @CinCout Jup, I thought that I had something wrong :) Thanks

Comment: Try outputing the state of inputfile.eof, instead of comparing it to "current". basically cout the variables that you have access to then you can decide from those values how to deal with them.

Comment: maybe make a "buffer" class to wrap the file object that gives you the current line then reads ahead to the next line or tells you there's no next line.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Yep, you are right there is a outer while loop which iterates using getline(inputFile, line). Sorry that I could not give the complete program. This is for a homework and I do not want to have plagiarism issues. should have stated these earlier :(

Comment: "I have to display a different error message if the error is at the last line of the input cpp file." This would be a hard to implement and generally useless feature. Are you sure you understand your assignment correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best solution I could think of. There is probably a better one.

```
std::ifstream input_file{ "file.txt };
std::vector<std::string> contents;

// fill vector with file contents
std::string cline;
while (std::getline(input_file, cline))
    contents.push_back(cline);

// now loop
for (const auto& line : contents) {
    //...
    if (&line == &contents.back()) {
        // do something at the end of file
    }
}
```

You can use an iterator version if you don't like the pointer comparison :)